# How to download a file uploaded to a private Facebook group using Graph API?

Tags: php, facebook, session, facebook-graph-api

I tried Googling for a problem, and found other unanswered topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721747/how-to-download-a-file-uploaded-to-a-private-facebook-group-using-graph-api)

So, I'm trying to make a PHP script that downloads a file from a **private/closed** group.
In Graph API, files are called "docs" ([source](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/)) and when you click on "docs", you get this example: http://d.pr/i/7DUW

I've managed to extract list with all the files and their download links.
To download a file, you have to open: www.facebook.com/download/{id}/{name}

So, how can I make a PHP script able to download those files ?
If there is no API for it, do I have to try injecting my session into PHP script somehow ?

Comment: Not sure if it works but you could try "file_put_contents("Tmpfile.docs", fopen("www.facebook.com/download/{id}/{name}", 'r'));"

Comment: Well, that doesn't work since I can't download a file without logging in.